# Need to split output into an javascript array

Tags: javascript, string

I receive the following payload from an external system. I need to return only the value of the "Cert Hash(sha256)" e.g. 267c797962b5ee69afd7fed3edc3fb41359a08a107fd801ddd5c5fd5925c09bb. This will change for each payload. I'm not great at regex so any help would be apprecitaed.

```
[
"X509 Certificate:",
"Version: 3",
"Serial Number: 61585b9996edef720f744fd2706ec3",
"Signature Algorithm:",
"    Algorithm ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 sha256RSA",
"    Algorithm Parameters:",
"    05 00",
"Issuer:",
"    CN=MWS Co TEST Medium Assurance Issuing CA - G2",
"    OU=For TEST purposes ONLY",
"    O=MWS Co Limited",
"    C=AU",
"  Name Hash(sha1): bd82dd1b8bdbc7951a3405fdba5d813b4c5e78c4",
"  Name Hash(md5): 7c0275b1e2ee55a2a3163308eee8da42",
"",
" NotBefore: 3/22/2020 10:00 AM",
" NotAfter: 3/23/2022 9:59 AM",
"",
"Subject:",
"    OU=NonProd",
"    OU=BRAVO",
"    O=MWS Co Limited",
"    OU=MULTI-ALLOWED",
"    CN=bravo-dev.MWSco.net.au",
"  Name Hash(sha1): 827558a1302f59fcccc2f5362c2e36eb5a23c66e",
"  Name Hash(md5): 140ac60c71220ba99ee5cd5c39317511",
"",
"Public Key Algorithm:",
"    Algorithm ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 RSA",
"    Algorithm Parameters:",
"    05 00",
"Public Key Length: 2048 bits",
"Public Key: UnusedBits = 0",
"    0000  30 82 99 0a 99 82 01 01  00 e7 d4 ba ae f0 55 3d",
"    0010  33 64 a6 92 81 e8 5c 7d  9c 52 de 15 a3 a7 00 0c",
"    0020  d6 87 38 03 f1 80 14 72  d4 c5 79 5d 36 fd 44 b7",
"    0030  2f ef 85 3b fe 80 5d 11  0c 12 91 a0 6c b5 4b 62",
"    0040  a9 25 7c 99 22 28 e1 fc  ef 13 3f 72 78 12 76 0d",
"    0050  26 bb 2a e0 ba 90 c4 53  27 96 d4 20 c9 8f 44 04",
"    0060  4e 65 35 dc 91 e3 ec 54  82 a6 0b 4b 7a 77 4b f9",
"    0070  98 9e a4 33 97 7e 75 0f  02 31 86 01 65 c8 89 6a",
"    0080  e8 fa 99 72 78 a9 4d d5  50 5d 49 f6 cc af d7 79",
"    0090  82 b0 72 97 92 5c a9 4d  c7 14 c7 68 0b 42 44 e7",
"    00a0  93 a1 23 84 53 a7 ea 69  2c 99 dc 21 df c3 46 c6",
"    00b0  54 6f 31 ac 25 11 f6 78  af 20 dc 56 f6 7d 4a 06",
"    00c0  f8 e6 7b ce 1a b5 20 b6  a9 98 50 8a 61 e4 ab 4b",
"    00d0  eb cd 8b c4 50 77 cd 3a  0e 1e 67 b8 50 50 b8 d5",
"    00e0  8f 2d 07 f5 8d f0 86 f9  2d 65 7a d2 33 ec 4d dc",
"    00f0  21 68 39 33 74 70 b2 2a  d3 07 95 44 0c 20 79 93",
"    0100  d8 b3 98 64 98 fc d6 82  7f 02 03 01 00 01",
"Certificate Extensions: 11",
"    2.5.29.19: Flags = 1(Critical), Length = 2",
"    Basic Constraints",
"        Subject Type=End Entity",
"        Path Length Constraint=None",
"",
"    2.5.29.15: Flags = 1(Critical), Length = 4",
"    Key Usage",
"        Digital Signature, Key Encipherment (a0)",
"",
"    2.5.29.37: Flags = 0, Length = 2a",
"    Enhanced Key Usage",
"        Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)",
"        Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)",
"        IP security IKE intermediate (1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2)",
"        Unknown Key Usage (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.17)",
"",
"    2.5.29.14: Flags = 0, Length = 16",
"    Subject Key Identifier",
"        53 ba f6 eb 92 2c aa 4b 8d 62 71 65 59 8c 9a 92 54 62 9d 4d",
"",
"    2.5.29.17: Flags = 0, Length = 32",
"    Subject Alternative Name",
"        DNS Name=bravo-dev.MWSco.net.au",
"        DNS Name=bravo-dev.MWSco.net.au",
"",
"    2.5.29.31: Flags = 0, Length = 56",
"    CRL Distribution Points",
"        [1]CRL Distribution Point",
"             Distribution Point Name:",
"                  Full Name:",
"                       URL=http://utf-crl.symauth.com/ca_7c0275b1e2ee55a2a3163308eee8da42/LatestCRL.crl",
"",
"    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1: Flags = 0, Length = 2b",
"    Authority Information Access",
"        [1]Authority Info Access",
"             Access Method=On-line Certificate Status Protocol (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)",
"             Alternative Name:",
"                  URL=http://utf-ocsp.symauth.com",
"",
"    2.5.29.35: Flags = 0, Length = 18",
"    Authority Key Identifier",
"        KeyID=58 bf 79 25 15 0e a0 61 dd 4e ca 40 8f b1 58 64 10 39 40 3d",
"",
"    2.5.29.32: Flags = 0, Length = 10b",
"    Certificate Policies",
"        [1]Certificate Policy:",
"             Policy Identifier=1.2.36.136533741.100",
"             [1,1]Policy Qualifier Info:",
"                  Policy Qualifier Id=CPS",
"                  Qualifier:",
"                       https://utf.MWSco.net.au/CPS",
"             [1,2]Policy Qualifier Info:",
"                  Policy Qualifier Id=User Notice",
"                  Qualifier:",
"                       Notice Text=Issued for TEST purposes ONLY under MWS Co utf. Refer to https://utf.MWSco.net.au/ for more information",
"        [2]Certificate Policy:",
"             Policy Identifier=1.2.36.136533741.200.2",
"             [2,1]Policy Qualifier Info:",
"                  Policy Qualifier Id=User Notice",
"                  Qualifier:",
"                       Notice Text=Certificates identified to a TEST Medium Assurance Level",
"",
"    2.16.840.1.113733.1.16.3: Flags = 0, Length = 1d",
"",
"    0000  30 1b 06 11 60 86 48 01  86 f8 45 01 10 01 05 01   0...`.H...E.....",
"    0010  02 a0 ea db 48 16 06 35  31 36 37 31 39            ....H..516719",
"0000: 30 1b\t\t\t\t\t; SEQUENCE (1b Bytes)",
"0002:    06 11\t\t\t\t\t; OBJECT_ID (11 Bytes)",
"0004:    |  60 86 48 01 86 f8 45 01  10 01 05 01 02 a0 ea db",
"0014:    |  48",
"         |     ; 2.16.840.1.113733.1.16.1.5.1.2.68857288",
"0015:    16 06\t\t\t\t\t; IA5_STRING (6 Bytes)",
"0017:       35 31 36 37 31 39                                 ; 516719",
"               ; \"516719\"",
"",
"    2.16.840.1.113733.1.16.5: Flags = 0, Length = 2b",
"",
"    0000  30 29 02 01 00 16 24 61  48 52 30 63 48 4d 36 4c   0)....$aHR0cHM6L",
"    0010  79 39 77 61 32 6b 74 63  6d 45 75 63 33 6c 74 59   y9wa2ktcmEuc3ltY",
"    0020  58 56 30 61 43 35 6a 62  32 30 3d                  XV0aC5jb20=",
"0000: 30 29\t\t\t\t\t; SEQUENCE (29 Bytes)",
"0002:    02 01\t\t\t\t\t; INTEGER (1 Bytes)",
"0004:    |  00",
"0005:    16 24\t\t\t\t\t; IA5_STRING (24 Bytes)",
"0007:       61 48 52 30 63 48 4d 36  4c 79 39 77 61 32 6b 74  ; aHR0cHM6Ly9wa2kt",
"0017:       63 6d 45 75 63 33 6c 74  59 58 56 30 61 43 35 6a  ; cmEuc3ltYXV0aC5j",
"0027:       62 32 30 3d                                       ; b20=",
"               ; \"aHR0cHM6Ly9wa2ktcmEuc3ltYXV0aC5jb20=\"",
"",
"Signature Algorithm:",
"    Algorithm ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 sha256RSA",
"    Algorithm Parameters:",
"    05 00",
"Signature: UnusedBits=0",
"    0000  1e 38 4c e4 68 0e 9a ab  fc e1 8b 0f fd 0e c4 49",
"    0010  5f e1 0c d1 d4 cc 91 15  4a c6 d4 e3 57 ee 66 f6",
"    0020  53 2f 2d ce d4 5d 9c 09  f4 39 f7 e7 ec ff 68 d5",
"    0030  9a fa d2 74 59 80 2d 09  13 bb 05 ac 06 16 05 85",
"    0040  21 30 fb af 63 50 d0 72  1b fc 14 b0 ab a1 02 22",
"    0050  20 5a 08 44 fd 2f 02 10  4b b2 25 71 d9 f6 cc b5",
"    0060  dc bb 27 77 92 2c 7e a2  cd d4 bb 6f bf 71 c8 f3",
"    0070  07 2e 37 88 e3 b9 93 e1  5f cb c2 87 c2 fc 8f 98",
"    0080  cf e0 57 1c 09 07 df 21  56 07 9c 77 f2 a2 40 42",
"    0090  9c 76 13 56 ff 9a c7 25  52 17 82 18 dc 84 6c 8c",
"    00a0  35 09 3a cf 98 bc a0 9b  22 14 94 ed b3 56 80 8b",
"    00b0  c6 9b a1 e7 a5 ac 02 02  10 e7 cd e8 7d 5b bc c1",
"    00c0  9b fd e8 53 76 26 40 0c  58 de b3 9a 72 f9 de 6e",
"    00d0  84 5a 57 ce 13 4a 02 5a  40 cf f6 33 3a 1a 04 a3",
"    00e0  e1 75 d6 d9 a6 4b 09 c7  35 4e 26 f7 73 97 e0 61",
"    00f0  8f 75 1a 89 ce d3 35 75  d0 7d 97 81 f8 9e 6a 2e",
"Non-root Certificate",
"Key Id Hash(rfc-sha1): 53baf6eb922caa4b8d627165598c9a9254629d4d",
"Key Id Hash(sha1): acaf6d277e90a319bae5ddaf7551fe0f9d4bd1d3",
"Key Id Hash(md5): a46f5271a6486ed08350e09211738f04",
"Key Id Hash(sha256): f68227295af39e21c7158df3680e88ed398845d2d88ba60dff662e4af658f570",
"Cert Hash(md5): 16785c4b0a55e002c93db7859b8b26c8",
"Cert Hash(sha1): 57a9c3b632ab43d4428654de7ce227087358f972",
"Cert Hash(sha256): 267c797962b5ee69afd7fed3edc3fb41359a08a107fd801ddd5c5fd5925c09bb",
"Signature Hash: 62abc9ff481ea14c13f09a8a9bee4b6ae0e62b5857eb403a47b5adf48a483529",
"CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully."
]
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Remember that this isn't a general help forum, it's a programming Q&A site, so if you haven't written _any_ code yet, that's step 1, and asking about problems with that code on Stackoverflow comes after step 1, not before. Give the [accepted posting topics](/help/on-topic) a read through if you haven't yet, and then also give the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) a read through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without regex too.

```js
var target = "Cert Hash(sha256)";
var value;
input.forEach(node => {
  var nodeArr = node.split(":");
  if (nodeArr[0] === target){
    value = nodeArr[1].trim();
  }
})
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex to find the string, you can try:

```
// arr can be your response array
arr.find(item => item.indexOf('Cert Hash(sha256)') >= 0).split(' ').pop(); // will return 267c797962b5ee69afd7fed3edc3fb41359a08a107fd801ddd5c5fd5925c09bb
```